# Blazor Client-Side Bootstrap-Select don't work

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a problem to use the complements of bootstrap-select from this page

[Bootstrap-Select Page](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/)

At moment to development  use my css and js configuration

[Scripts Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QakVt.png)

[Control Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0VH0.png)

[Control Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN25R.png)

But don't produce empty result, the html code  should change according to the use from scripts but stay match, to exception of control visibility, its hide and don't work.

I have running my app with Blazor Web Assembly Client Side with DotNetCore version 3.2. Bootstrap 4.5

Help me, please...

Thank you...

[Git Example](https://github.com/evillabong/BlazorApp1.git)

Comment: welcome to SO you might want to consider using github.com as a way to help you with source to show us... pictures aren't exactly the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering, my git repository: https://github.com/evillabong/BlazorApp1.git